# Cant ran app on android Lolilop 5.1 , but working on Higher versions : Firebase authentification fails

Tags: android, firebase, visual-studio-2015, firebase-authentication

Developed android application with two users: Admin- user... using Firebase to save data into.
I run the app for the tests on different android versions , it is working expect for Lolilop 5.1 (both virtual machine and device)  , Authentification fails for the admin , but for the simple user it is working.
Does it have to do with Firebase ? i updated all google service , but still the same.

Does anyone experienced this before ?
Please any recommendations to trouble shoot this issue , cant find any hint ?
Thank you.

Comment: As same code working for simple user, it is definitely not a Firebase or android issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post the relevant pieces of code in your question as it makes helping you an awful lot easier :)